# In my view something unwanted shows up

Tags: android, canvas, android-view

I am building a snake game app.
So fur it works, except for the what it shows.
For some reason it shows two snakes: the original snake that moves and can be controlled, and another begginging of a snake that doesn't do anything.

Before that I drew at every cycle in the loop a background color, so it would cover the last canvas, and there was no problem.

Then I decided to divide the snake from the background, so I have made the snake canvas's background transparent and that it would clear the canvas each time it wants to draw a new canvas (each loop-to move the snake).

Here is the code:

The run of the thread:

```
public void run() {
    long stepPerSecond=1000/FPS;
    long startTime;
    long sleepTime;
    while(isRunning){
        Canvas c=null;
        startTime=System.currentTimeMillis();

        try{
            c=this.getHolder().lockCanvas();
            synchronized (this.getHolder()) {
                this.onDraw(c);
                }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
        }
        finally{
            if(c!=null){
                this.getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
            }

        }
        sleepTime= stepPerSecond-(System.currentTimeMillis()-startTime);
        if(sleepTime>0)
            try {
                Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }

}
```

The snake's ondraw (it uses the snake's class on draw):

```
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawColor(color.transparent, Mode.CLEAR);
    snake.onDraw(canvas);
}
```

The snake's class onDraw:

```
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    switch(dirTransfare(dir)){
    case 1://RIGHT
        xLoc=xLoc+PART_SIZE;
    break;
    case 2://UP
        yLoc=yLoc-PART_SIZE;
    break;
    case -1://LEFT
        xLoc=xLoc-PART_SIZE;
    break;
    case -2://DOWN
        yLoc=yLoc+PART_SIZE;
    break;
    }//swich
    int x=xLoc;
    int y=yLoc;
        for(Brick bp:SnakeBody){
            bp.setR(0+x, 0+y, PART_SIZE+x, PART_SIZE+y);
            canvas.drawRect(bp.getR(),bp.getP());
            int xtemp=bp.getX();
            int ytemp=bp.getY();
            bp.setX(x);
            bp.setY(y);
            x=xtemp;
            y=ytemp;
        }//for each 
}//onDraw
```

Here is the mainActivity, which summons the snakeVew and the backgorundView (snake is the game view and the background is the arena)

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity  {
GameView gv;
ImageView left;
ImageView right;
ImageView up;
ImageView down;
Arena a;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    /*requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    v= new GameView1(this);
    setContentView(v);
    */
    gv= new GameView(this);
    a=new Arena(this);
    setContentView(R.layout.game_view);
    LinearLayout surface = new LinearLayout(this);
    LinearLayout backGround = new LinearLayout(this);
    surface = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.surface);
    backGround = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.background);
    surface.addView(gv);
    backGround.addView(a);

    left=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.left);
    right=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.right);
    up=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.up);
    down=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.down);

    left.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(gv.snake.getDir()!="LEFT"&&gv.snake.getDir()!="RIGHT"){
            gv.snake.Left();
            }
        }
    });
    right.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(gv.snake.getDir()!="RIGHT"&&gv.snake.getDir()!="LEFT"){
            gv.snake.Right();   
            }
        }
    });
    up.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(gv.snake.getDir()!="UP"&&gv.snake.getDir()!="DOWN"){
            gv.snake.Up();  
            }
        }
    });
    down.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(gv.snake.getDir()!="DOWN"&&gv.snake.getDir()!="UP"){
            gv.snake.Down();
            }
        }
    });



}
```

The problem is not in the background (the arena class); I have alredy took it down and confirmed that (it worked the same away, with the bug, even without using the arena class).

Here is how it looks with the bug:

http://i.tinyuploads.com/q7oztz.jpg

(you can see two snakes - the long one is the real one)
The blue background is from class arena.

Any ideas? Tnx for help :D

Comment: it's really important for me, can anyone try to help me?